# 404 Error when accessing image in pub/media

Tags: 404-page, media-images, .htaccess, magento-2.2.5

Ive been struggling with this for a few weeks now and dont seem to be getting anywhere. I have installed a module that reads images from a directory 'pub/media/import' however when I navigate to the image I get a 404 error. If I move the image up a directory the image works fine. Any ideas? I assume this is something to do with .htaccess but im unsure which file.

Working: https://www.example.com/pub/media/1.jpg,

404 error: https://www.example.com/pub/media/import/1.jpg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was slved this issue using configuring htaccess file in server. also can set a permission for media chmod -Rf 777 pub/media

Comment: could you please add htaccess config here I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @NitinPawar . Download fresh magento 2 (Your version) and upload it's /pub htaccess file into your project pub folder . please

Comment: I'm facing issue for single instance I have copied file from another instance with same magento version. Still I am facing the same issue.